# take a part of a string in java

Tags: java, regex, string, token

I have a string which includes 4 attributes with 3 spaces between them(name,surname,email,tel). For example:

```
"Mike   Tyson   mike@hotmail.com   0 999 999 99 99"
```

I need to take e-mail from this string. I searched for regex and tokens but can't find anything. Thank you.

Comment: Please post the regex and code that you've tried and that didn't work for you.

Comment: Yeah, if its a rigid form, split on the 3 spaces like @Pshemo says.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. [`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) your string using 3 spaces to get array of tokens
2. take token which interests you (here it will be indexed as `[2]`)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following and extract group 1:

```
^[^\\s]+\\s+[^\\s]+\\s+([^\\s]+)
```

Code:

```
String str = "Mike   Tyson   mike@hotmail.com   0 999 999 99 99";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("^[^\\s]+\\s+[^\\s]+\\s+([^\\s]+)").matcher(str);

while (matcher.find()) {
   System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code snippet -

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ExtractMail{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String str = "Mike   Tyson   mike@hotmail.com   0 999 999 99 99";
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+").matcher(str);

        while (matcher.find()) {
           System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String string = "Mike   Tyson   mike@hotmail.com   0 999 999 99 99";
System.out.println(string.split("   ")[2]); // your email
```

It's simple. Use a method `split` for getting String array and call on needed element to index.

Answer (score 1):

One liner...

```
String s = "Mike   Tyson   mike@hotmail.com   0 999 999 99 99";
String email = s.trim().split(" ")[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

As requested by OP here is a version with Regex:

```
public static void test()
{
    String str = "Mike   Tyson   mike@hotmail.com   0 999 999 99 99";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[^ ]*@[^ ]*").matcher(str);

    while (matcher.find()) {
       System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
    }
}
```

`[^ ]*@[^ ]*` matches any character (except space) around the `@` character.